# trying to post an ajax to django view method and totally failing

Tags: ajax, django, csrf

I am utterly lost, I've read a number of answers and tutorials to this question, including information on the django site, and I have no idea how to deal with this.

My problem is very simple.  I want make a simple post request using ajax and get back some information.  I can't even get into the view method on the django side.

Here is the code

```
#urls.py
url(r'^spitback/$', 'spitback'),

#views.py
def spitback(request):
    logger.debug("\n\n\nspitback");
    logger.debug("request.method = {0}".format(request.method))
    return HttpResponse("helloooooo")
```

the javascript:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    return(/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}

$.ajaxSetup({
    crossDomain: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});


function testpost() { 
  $.ajax({ 
    type:"POST", 
    url:'/login', 
    data:{
        'key':'val', 
       'csrfmiddlewaretoken':"TB5gktJzHdowOtXR4u1BpjGABoKbJ2IQ"
    },        
    contentType:"application/json;charset=utf-8", 
    dataType:"json", 
    success: function(data) { alert('data = ' + data);}, 
    error: function(ts) { alert('ts = ' + ts)}
  }); 

  return false; 
}

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        console.log("document loaded for template login.django");
         $( "#somebutton" ).click( 
            testpost
        );
    });
```

At this point I'm just trying to test the post feature, but when I try it out I clearly see from the logs that the view method for "spitback" isn't even getting called.

Someone please help me, I am at my wits end.

Comment: That URL should be '/spitback' instead of login

Answer (score 1):

That should be:

```
 $( "#somebutton" ).click( 
     testpost();
 );
```

And the `url` in your ajax call is also wrong.